# Group By Max(Date) and Count(Items) within that period only

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

I have a table with items held in a number of boxes at various dates. I want to output the number of items held in the most recent period.

Input:

```
Name    Item    Date
Box 1   ItemA   7/31/2023
Box 1   ItemB   7/31/2023
Box 1   ItemC   7/31/2023
Box 1   ItemA   6/30/2023
Box 2   ItemA   12/31/2022
Box 2   ItemB   12/31/2022
Box 2   ItemC   12/31/2022
Box 2   ItemD   12/31/2022
Box 2   ItemA   3/31/2023
Box 2   ItemB   3/31/2023
Box 2   ItemC   3/31/2023
Box 2   ItemD   3/31/2023
Box 2   ItemE   3/31/2023
Box 2   ItemF   3/31/2023
```

Output:

```
Name    Max_Date    #Items
Box 1   7/31/2023   3
Box 2   3/31/2023   6
```

The code I have returns the Max(Date) but instead of counting only items in that period it counts all items associated with the box.

```
Name    Max_Date    #Items
Box 1   7/31/2023   4
Box 2   3/31/2023   10
```

Do I need a group by and 2 inner joins?

```
Select Distinct t.[Name], r.LastUpdate, r.itemCount
From (
        Select [Name], Max(Date) as LastUpdate,Count([Item]) as itemCount
        From Table
        Group by [Name]
    ) r
INNER JOIN Table t
ON t.[Name] = r.[Name] AND t.[Date] = r.LastUpdate
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT item)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Please show your query

Comment: Query added now

Answer (score 1):

You need one `GROUP BY` in the derived table (to get the latest dates), and then another `GROUP BY` to get the counts.

```
Select t.[Name], r.LastUpdate, count(*) as itemCount
From (
        Select [Name], Max(Date) as LastUpdate
        From Table
        Group by [Name]
    ) r
INNER JOIN Table t
    ON t.[Name] = r.[Name] AND t.[Date] = r.LastUpdate
GROUP BY t.[Name], r.LastUpdate
```

**Edit**: You can also do rank over partition to get the latest dates' rows:

```
Select r.[Name], r.Date, count(*) as itemCount
From (
        Select tt.*, rank() over (partition by name order by name, date desc) rnk
        from Table tt
     ) r
where r.rnk = 1
GROUP BY r.[Name], r.Date
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/1bDrAlba

Comment: thanks. This is what I need. I couldnt figure out where to put the second group by.